# Leaving a fragment's activity and then returning appears to erase the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

**Update #3**

In a further effort to understand what was happening here, I started the Activity that loads the VideoView through startActivityForResult feeding it a value (25) as an expected requestCode. The calling Activity's onActivityResult requestCode is not not 25. (It's consistently 131097, which I am sure is that specific and consistent only as an artifact of the memory usage during testing).

**Update #2**

I did a forced backstack pop upon returning from the VideoView activity and instead of popping back along the fragment view, it popped back the container. Weird.

**Slight update**

I added

```
    FragmentManager fm = this.getFragmentManager();
    backCount = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
```

at onCreateView, onResume and onSaveInstanceState to see if the backstack count is erased. It is not. So... I guess the backstack isn't actually erased, it just isn't accessed anymore by the Back button? Almost as though the Container of the fragment has the focus, not the contentst. Or something. I am full blown confused here.

**End update**

I asked a similar question previously, but this a little more specific and oddly vexing.

I have a series of fragments that allow a user to choose a amongst various categorized video clips. Starting from the Video Clips view, the user chooses from "Highlights," "Interviews," etc. Once a subcategory is selected, the user chooses a video to watch. Going from the Video Clips to a subsection and then hitting the Back button works fine. However, if the user chooses a video in the subsection, then hits back, they are returned to the subsection (good), and if they hit Back again, nothing happens. As if there is no more backstack.

Here is the relevant code:

Backstack creation:

```
protected void showSubmenu(BaseFragment fragment, String fragmentTagname) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentSubmenu, fragment, fragmentTagname);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        //transaction.add(R.id.fragmentSubmenu, fragment, fragmentTagname);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Transition from submenu to video:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Video video = (Video) this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String url = video.link.substring(29);;
    url = Kriptonic.getEncryptedURL(url);
    uri = Uri.parse(url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(_myActivity, VideoClips.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

As always, thank you for your time.